# Integrate ASP.NET (C#) into PHP

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

Is it possible to call a C# method and asp.net page through php?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within a PHP generated page you can **definitely** link to a ASP.NET page.

If you want to call a C# method within a PHP script, I would suggest you using a **RESTful API** or **SOAP** to invoke C#'s method remotely. Your ASP.NET application server will host the WebService, and your PHP script will be the client.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure what your scenario is, but you may check out [Phalanger](http://phalanger.codeplex.com/).

Phalanger is an open-source compiler of PHP to .NET which also adds some extensions to PHP that make it possible to call .NET methods (and similarly, you can call compiled PHP from C#).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean, however it is possible to call [page methods](http://aspalliance.com/1922) which have to be called via `POST` with content-type = "application/json; charset=utf-8". There are [jQuery tactics](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) to do this from a web page.